# How to check if a string ends with a number, without regex?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to check if the last character of a string ends with an int. I would like to avoid using a regular expression, because I think it is very hard, but if there is no smoother way of doing it, I will try it.

I basically tried something that looks like this:

```
text.EndsWith(INTEGER)]
```

Comment: This doesn't compile... `I don't would like to avoid regex` are you saying you want to stay away from `regex` or... Also what's the issue you are seeing, what's the expected output?

Comment: Do you just want to know if the last character is a decimal digit (`0` through `9`) using the "normal" digits? Or do you want to also accept decimal digits in [other writing systems](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)? What about non-decimal digits, like fractions and roman numeral characters (e.g., ½)?

Comment: @JoeSewell he specified `int` in the question body

Comment: `bool result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && char.IsDigit(text[text.Length - 1]);`

Comment: @OlivierRogier why did you change the question completely by converting from "check last character is digit" to "check string ends with an integer"?

Comment: `char.IsDigit((text is string str) && str.Length > 0 ? str[str.Length - 1] : ' ')` another alternative and dirty :)

Comment: @Alex_Joo A *number* and an *integer* are not a *digit*... can you update the title and the body to help others to not be confused and to allow some to remove the wrong duplicates, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Boolean result = char.IsDigit(text[text.Length - 1]);
```

Comment: Note this returns true for number characters in other languages.  So it matches more than just 0-9.

Comment: Edited to IsDigit

Answer (score 4):

using linq Last method and Isdigit function

```
bool isDigit = Char.IsDigit(("one1").Last());
```

Comment: Parenthesis around the string are not necessary.

Comment: @RufusL I know, It makes for a cleaner code for me

Comment: Extra parenthesis are the opposite of clean code, except where operator precedence is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the last character and try parse it to integer:

```
private static bool IsStringEndsWithDigit(string str)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        return false;
        // or throw an exception
        // throw new Exception("string can not be empty");
    }
    string last = str.Substring(str.Length - 1, 1);
    int num;
    var isNum = int.TryParse(last, out num);
    return isNum;
}
```

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I don't understand why it didn't work (in the example it returns false). also, the question is not relevant to a different culture the question is about identifying digit at the end of a string. I don't understand why downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastChar = text.Last();
var endsWithNum = lastChar >= '0' && lastChar <= '9';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string s = "hello world0";
int len = s.Length;
List<char> digits = new List<char>(){'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
if (digits.Contains(s[len - 1]))
{
    Console.WriteLine("last character is digits");
}
```